# how to fix site for IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having tough time finding out what CSS property to change to get my page working in IE7.

Page is [here](http://cloudninetech.com/newsite/site/homepage.html)

It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE8 but not in IE7 (maybe IE6) as well.

Notice that navigation menu goes up and `#header` that contains logo shrinks to a small size...

/hate IE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.content` has a height of 4.2 pixels. Try using a `border-top:4px solid #whateverhex` instead of using a 41px high repeating gif.

Then remove `height:4.2px`.

Alternative would be `#nav { clear:both; }`

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that IE isnt using the Psuedo `after` class, which is where you clear your float.  you can just add a height to the #header, or clear your float in a line break tag after the content.